# Limit inside the exp function

Tags: limits, exponential-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

I do not understand the following limit-rule:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp(f(x))=\exp(\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x))$$

Why is that true?

Comment: Do you know that the exponential function is continuous?

Comment: It is true if and only if $f$ is continuous

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE: The continuity of $f$ is not needed, only that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists. The essential point is that $\exp$ is continuous.

Comment: Okay thanks!!!!

Comment: Sorry I read limit inside f(x). Right.

Answer (score 0):

Since the exponential function $\exp(\cdot) : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, if the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists, then it can be indeed written that :
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp(f(x))=\exp(\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x))$$